# JButton showing ellipses

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to set up a GUI in Java using the Swing library. I have created a custom button class that has a custom initializer to make things easier. It is below:

```
public class JTButton extends JButton {

    char type;

    public JTButton(String title, ActionListener listener, char type) {
        super(title);
        this.type = type;
        addActionListener(listener);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setFont(new Font("Monospaced", 1, 10));
        setBorderPainted(false);
        if (type == 'h') {
            setFont(new Font("Monospaced", 1, 24));
        }
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void setColor(Color t, Color b) {
        setBackground(b);
        setForeground(t);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the program it is showing elipses in my grid of buttons, like below.

[16x16 grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9758.png)

[image: 16x16 grid]

It should look like this (this is the smaller grid):

[9x9 grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PC4u.png)
[image: 9x9 grid]

I saw some stuff on `GetPreferredSize()` but haven't been able to make anything work. Let me know what I can do!

Extra info: Running in macOS, the grid is set up in a GridLayout

Comment: I am guessing the 16 x 16 buttons are to small to display the text. Try making the buttons have a min width large enough to display the text.

Comment: 1) *"Let me know what I can do!"* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/)! 2) But firstly, you might try calling `pack()` on the `JFrame` - just before `setVisible(true)`. It seems the GUI is too small for the content. 3) Also note there is no method by the name `GetPreferredSize()`, but is one with `getPreferredSize()`. In Java, case matters. This is a good time to be using `@Overrides` notation for compile time checking of method name spelling & argument types.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are artificially constraining the sizes or preferred sizes of some of your components rather than letting the layout managers and the component's own preferred sizes do this work. That's the best solution -- and don't forget to call `pack()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run my program, it shows ellipses in my grid of buttons.

The ellipses are appearing because the buttons are too small for the text to appear.

This is happening because ultimately you're not using Layout Managers correctly, as HovercraftFullOfEels has mentioned. To explain how to use Layout Managers properly is far too big of an answer *(and not what I think you're looking for)*, so instead I will provide you with some quick ways to get rid of the ellipses.

Here are a few ways to remove the ellipses...

### "Quick Fix" Solutions:

#### 1. Modify the JButton Margins.

The margins on JButtons are notoriously small. You can resize them to provide extra room for your text to appear.

You can do this in your JTButton constructor by calling...

```
setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

*Don't forget to `import java.awt.Insets;`*

You can see the documentation for this function [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)).

#### 2. Make each JButton larger.

Since you are using a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html), you can make each button larger by making your "Grid container" larger. The buttons will stretch out to fill the available space evenly.

Depending on what [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you're using for the *parent* of the Grid container, there will be different ways to resize it. It's outside the scope of this answer to go into depth on those.

Comment: No, the canonical solution, which you have not mentioned is to let the components and the layouts set their own sizes by avoiding calling setSize or setPreferredSize, and by calling `pack()` on the top level window before displaying it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's another potential solution that you should write an answer for _(and it's admittedly the best option mentioned so far)_. However, I still don't see what's wrong with the answers I've given; **both can be used to remove the ellipses**. If there's anything I can do to improve my answer, let me know.

Comment: Yes they can be used to remove the ellipses, but they are wrong. His primary problem is that he is not using the layout managers as they were intended. If this is not addressed in your answer, then it too is wrong.

Comment: Okay, so what should I do to improve my answer? Should I address what you've mentioned, or will you post it?